# steam windows are empty + "glxinfo: command not found"

Tags: steam, mesa, endeavouros

I'm new to Arch,
coming from Ubuntu I have very recently installed EndeavourOS
today I installed Steam, but my windows are [shown empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBVbR.png)
Looking for some solution I notice that often the finger is pointed at `glxinfo`
so I run

```
[yakforward@yoga-720 ~]$ sudo pacman -S vulkan-intel
[sudo] password for yakforward: 
warning: vulkan-intel-21.2.1-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (1)         Old Version  New Version  Net Change

extra/vulkan-intel  21.2.1-1     21.2.1-1       0,00 MiB

Total Installed Size:  9,99 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0,00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                     [----------------------] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                   [----------------------] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                        [----------------------] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                  [----------------------] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) reinstalling vulkan-intel                    [----------------------] 100%
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/2) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
(2/2) Checking which packages need to be rebuilt
[yakforward@yoga-720 ~]$ glxinfo | grep -i vulkan
bash: glxinfo: command not found
```

this is my neofetch

```
                     ./o.                  yakforward@yoga-720 
                   ./sssso-                ------------------- 
                 `:osssssss+-              OS: EndeavourOS Linux x86_64 
               `:+sssssssssso/.            Host: 80X6 Lenovo YOGA 720-13IKB 
             `-/ossssssssssssso/.          Kernel: 5.13.13-arch1-1 
           `-/+sssssssssssssssso+:`        Uptime: 1 hour, 29 mins 
         `-:/+sssssssssssssssssso+/.       Packages: 1080 (pacman), 7 (snap) 
       `.://osssssssssssssssssssso++-      Shell: bash 5.1.8 
      .://+ssssssssssssssssssssssso++:     Resolution: 1920x1080 
    .:///ossssssssssssssssssssssssso++:    DE: GNOME 40.4 
  `:////ssssssssssssssssssssssssssso+++.   WM: Mutter 
`-////+ssssssssssssssssssssssssssso++++-   WM Theme: Adwaita 
 `..-+oosssssssssssssssssssssssso+++++/`   Theme: Adwaita-dark [GTK2/3] 
   ./++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++/:.     Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
  `:::::::::::::::::::::::::------``       Terminal: gnome-terminal 
                                           CPU: Intel i5-7200U (4) @ 3.100GHz 
                                           GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620 
                                           Memory: 2380MiB / 7675MiB
```

do you have any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: `pkgfile -s filename` will tell you what package owns a particular file.

Answer (score 0):

`vulkan-intel` doesn't provide `glxinfo`, it is
`Intel's Vulkan mesa driver`. There are different packages for nVidia and Radeon.

Install `mesa-demos` (provides `glxinfo`), it is not specific to your GPU, it provides information about them. Alternately, there is a standalone `glxinfo` package in AUR.

Comment: I have installed `mesa-demos` and rebooted, but the problem persist, steam windows are still empty

Comment: Running steam from terminal may tell the error.